# how to disable data retrieval on jqgrid load

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

jqgrid is used to show stock status from server. Data is retrieved in json format using controller in url parameter:

```
url: 'Grid/GetData'
```

Getting data (even 0 rows) takes some time. This causes noticeable delay on page load.

How to disable GetData controller call on initial jqgrid load?
On initial load empty grid should appear, without rows.

Data should retrieved if such command is issued by user:

- search criteria is entered
- enter is pressed in search toolbar
- refresh button in jqgrid toolbar is pressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just use `datatype: 'local'` at the beginning. If you want to load the data from the server you should change `datatype` to 'json' with respect of `setGridParam` method and trigger `reloadGrid`.

In many scenarios like master/detailed grid I use the way. At the beginning the detailed grid has `datatype: 'local'`. If a row will be selected at the master grid I set `datatype` to 'json' for the detailed grid and reload it. In the `postData` of the detailed grid will be used the id of selected row from the master grid.

Comment: Thank you. I added datatype:'local' and in loadComplete called `$grid.setGridParam({datatype:'json'})` It looks like this enables normal data load if any subsequent command is issued. I hope that this does not cause any side effects

Comment: @Andrus: You are welcome! I think you can use `$(this).jqGrid('setGridParam', {datatype: 'json'});` inside of `loadComplete`. If you call later `.trigger('reloadGrid')` or if the user click on sorting, paging and so on the grid will be reloaded at the first time from the server.

Comment: Thank you. Site.Master contains `$.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true`. Why my call did'nt cause error? loadComplete method handler is defined in included .js file whic his called form loadComplete. In this case $(this) does not work, I changed it to `$grid.jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' })`

Comment: @Andrus: How you call another method? `this` inside of `loadComplete` is DOM of `<table>` so you can use `anotherMethod.call(this, data)`. Important is only that you should define `anotherMethod` not with `function anotherMethod(data)` which don't support `this` in the strict model. If you define as `var anotherMethod = function(data)` or as a *method* of another object you can use `this` inside of `anotherMethod`. About another problem: you should verify *where* you use `$.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true`. If should be placed after including `grid.locale-en.js` but *before* `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`.

Comment: It is best practice to pass this explicity as method parameter. `anotherMethod.call(this, data)` is bad. call() should never used.

Comment: @Andrus: I disagree with you about `.call(this,`. If you open jQuery UI code for example you will find a lot of such examples. Why you think that its? Where you read about this?

Comment: This opinion is based in my javascript experience. call simply passes additional argument. It is better to pass all arguments explicity as parameters, no reason to make exception for one argument. jQuery UI needs to call existing methods which do not have this as parameter. New methods designed for multiple objects should have this as explicit parameter.